# Is writing 2K13 technically correct?

Tags: number-systems

As seen in the video game title [NBA 2K13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NBA_2K13), they have used 2K13. But is it technically correct? I think that 2K13 => 200013!

**EDIT:** *Sorry for the wrong reference to Roman Numerals*

Comment: (-1) for "I know that K is used in the Roman Numeral System to represent 3 Zeros i.e. 000." - At least do some googling before you make such false claims.

Comment: I read it somewhere, hence got confused.

Comment: You should have complained [eleven years ago](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NBA_2K1) :)

Comment: It's not a complain, an acquaintance whom I told that I don't think  2K13 is correct brought this up to me, so was just confirming.

Comment: 2K13 is perfectly correct in the prefix-postfix SMS-generation positional notation system.

Comment: It's common in Electronic Eng. - e.g. 3v3 is 3.3v, 10M2 resistor is 10.2 MOhm. Note actually that voltage is the only time I've ever seen it done with the unit; usually it's just the multiplier.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The use of **K** as an abbreviation for $1000$ has nothing to do with Roman numerals: the Roman numeral for $1000$ is **M**. It derives from the prefix *kilo-*, used in the metric system to indicate $1000$ of some base unit. It is a non-standard usage, so there is no standard of technical correctness. In this case you should think of the **K** simply as an abbreviation for *thousand* and read it *two thousand thirteen*.

Answer (score 8):

1. $K\neq \text{''000''}$
2. K does not correlate whatsoever with the roman numerals.
3. In decimal notation, numbers are written as $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}a_n10^n$, therefore, 2K13 is not technically correct if we are using the standard decimal notation. Here it is to mean $2*K+13$ where $K=1000$

Answer (score 8):

No, it is not “wrong”. The sense in which $\rm K$ is used here is indisputable  because it is only a video game title, not to be taken too seriously. What they meant here was $\rm 2K + 13$.

Roman numerals are **not** connected with the metric system whatsoever. [$\rm K$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilo-) belongs to the metric system, and [$\rm M$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals) is the real Roman numeral for 1000.